# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpected

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Ya lo reinstale como dicen en post anteriores, y me vuelve a salir el error, funciona por lapsos de tiempo habia cambiado los puertos por unos problemas que tenia con vmware, me dio un error en phpmy admin asi que decidi desinstalar vware y reinstalar XAMP, aun asi me salen estos errores.

El error que me aparece en PHPMyAdmin es el siguiente:
El almacenamiento de configuración phpMyAdmin no está completamente configurado, algunas funcionalidades extendidas fueron deshabilitadas. Averigüe por qué.

O, de modo alternativo, utilizar la pestaña «Operaciones» de cualquier base de datos para configurarlo allí.

Ya busque y los metodos no me funcionaron

```
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
10:30:27 p. m.  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

El error que aparece en logs es el siguiente

```
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-02 16:41:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-012022-01-02 16:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-01-02 16:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-02 16:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
```

Comment: Mira a ver si esto te ayuda: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-fix-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-error/ ...  de todos modos, si dices que te funciona "por lapsos de tiempo" es probable que otro programa esté lanzando tambien escuchas en ese puerto.  Cuando te pase de nuevo primero comprueba si el puerto 3306 ya esta en uso mediante `netstat -anp|find 3306` y si lo esta preguntate porque y o bien lo desinstalas o bien matas el proceso.  Supongo que ya lo sabias, es solo por si acaso.

Comment: "funciona por lapsos de tiempo": ¿cae cada vez que usás Workbench? (dado que también publicaste [esta pregunta](/q/507180)). Eso debería darte una pista ;)